# SWIFT: App was designed for a RTL language, but when i run in on an RTL based language it mirrors

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

so im developing an app that's directed to work on both RTL and LTR languages.
I built all the UI based on the RTL design, but didnt figure that I tested in on an english based device.
Im now testing it on hebrew based device, and the mirrors, i tried changing the Localization native development region in the Info.plist to he, but it still mirrors the app.

[image: Thats the desired behaviour]

[image: And thats what happening when running the app on hebrew device]

first image is the desired behaviour and second one is whats happening when running the app on hebrew device

Comment: please share the screenshot of current and desired behaviour

Comment: Did you use leading/trailing constraints or left/right. You should use the former and layout for the locale in which you are developing. The layout will then flip automatically when an opposite locale is in use.

Comment: @KeshuR. i just added in the question

Comment: @Paulw11 I used leading/trailing constraints, the layout flips nicely, but it should flip on hebrew device, i want it to flip on english devices

Comment: If you *always* want RTL appearance then use left & right constraints not leading & trailing.

Comment: @Paulw11 I dont want it to always be on RTL, i want it to mirror the app only on LTR languages